# Failed to lookup view "forms" in the views directory "./views"

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, rendering, html-rendering

This is the code that i've been using to study

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');


// Config
    // Template Engine
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
        app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
        app.set("views", "./views");
    // Body Parser
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // MySql connection
        const sequelize = new Sequelize('teste', 'root', 'idohaveanotherpasswordhere', {
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: 'mysql'
    });

// Routes
    app.get('/form', function(req, res){
        res.render('forms');
    });

    app.post('/add', function(req, res){
        res.send("Texto: "+req.body.titulo+" Conteudo: "+req.body.conteudo);
    });


//localhost:8081
app.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("Server running on URL http://localhost:8081");
});
```

in this section

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res){
        res.render('formulario');
    });
```

the code is not finding the view in the "view/layouts/formulario.handlebars", how can i solve that?
Here is the problem

> 

Error: Failed to lookup view "anotherform" in views directory "./views"
   at Function.render (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
   at C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\index.js:26:13
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
   at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
   at next (C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)

> 

i tried changing the name in the () to res.render('anotherform') and the file name or using the main page, it did not work, but when i use res.send("Some text") it works

Comment: What is the path to the view file and what is the path to the layout file?

Comment: It looks like `formulario` is _not_ a layout and so should be located at `views/formulario.handlebars`

Comment: C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\VSCODE\ProjetoNODE\views\layouts\formulario.handlebars

Comment: there is also main.handlebears in the same path that works as the default looking style, the only thing i added on it is {{{body}}} between the body tags, both are working as html file

Comment: As I said above, `formulario.handlebars` should _not_ be in the `views/layouts/` directory. `view/layouts/` is for layout files only. You need to move it to `views/formulario.handlebars`.